# Why does the code give me "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL"

Tags: angularjs

This is the angular code:

```
angular.forEach($scope.teams, function(value){
                  Dashboard.get({dashboardCtrl: "team"，guid: value.guid}, function(response){
                  });
              });
```

Thanks,

Comment: Simply use [JSHint](http://jshint.com/) next time right away _before_ asking a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comma you have after `"team"` is not a proper comma. Replace `，` with `,` as JavaScript doesn’t understand what that token is.